# Dataset Filters in one row

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, c#-3.0

is there any possiblities like this select two conditions in one dataview like

Childds.Tables("ColumnList").DefaultView.RowFilter = customername='hello'

```
dv = Childds.Tables("ColumnList").DefaultView()
```

it has given correct answer but

**Childds.Tables("ColumnList").DefaultView.RowFilter = customername='hello' or customername='hai'**

```
dv = Childds.Tables("ColumnList").DefaultView()
```

In this case it takes only first one and ignore the second or condition 
how to write the rowfilter to select when the customers are multiple

Comment: but it dont take second argument it will filter the data on only first condition

Comment: the rows containing hai and hello are coming in second condition but it will retrieve only hello customer

Comment: He means that you should accept answers on your previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

The possible answers here: [DataView RowFilter Syntax [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)
I believe it is enought to you something like this:

```
dataView.RowFilter = "CustomerName IN ('hello', 'hai')";
```

Comment: we put that condition in one string strfilter in that case it wont work for me thats the problem when i debug the string shows the value but the dataview filter cant work it on two things

Comment: It's difficult to determine the cause of this issue due to the lack of information. Would you please provide us with a code illustrating the problem? Improve your answer with these additions.

Comment: Childds.Tables("ColumnList").DefaultView.RowFilter=strFilterCustomer dv = Childds.Tables("ColumnList").DefaultView  in strfiltercustomer first time it will take 3 conditions like customername in(' ','','') its working next time it take 2 arguments ('','')but it will take first one only second one is ignoring why

Comment: how to attach my code file please tell me its better to understand

Comment: @SuribabuKandukuri: Use "Edit" action on your question. Use [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)  for code formatting

Comment: <code> Childds.Table("ColumnList").DefaultView.RowFilter= strFilterCustomer dv = Childds.Tables("ColumnList").DefaultView</code> in strfiltercustomer first time it will take 3 conditions like customername in(' ','','') its working next time it take 2 arguments ('','')but it will take first one only second one is ignoring why

Comment: send me ur mail id i will send attached code file to u Thank you